# Is Brice Clotaire Oligui Nguema, the President of Gabon, related to Teodoro Obiang Nguema Mbasogo of Equatorial Guinea or to Francisco Nguema?

Tags: political-history

Gabon recently experienced a coup d'etat in which Brice Clotaire Oligui Nguema was installed as President.

It would be historically relevant to ascertain whether he has consanguineal kinship to Teodoro Obiang Nguema Mbasogo of Equatorial Guinea, which is North of Gabon, and the nature of that kinship is, if any.

As far as I know, it has not been reported in the news or on Wikipedia.

I searched articles on all major news outlets, The Guardian, and The Intercept. The significance of the question relates to myriad important issues such as possible inter-family corruption and overthrow of African states. It could be that Nguema is a popular surname in that part of the world and no kinship connection is present.

Comment: I searched articles on all major news outlets, The Guardian, and The Intercept. The significance of the question relates to myriad important issues such as possible inter-family corruption and overthrow of African states. It could be that Nguema is a popular surname in that part of the world and no kinship connection is present.

Comment: According to https://forebears.io/surnames/nguema, it's an extremely common surname in the area.

Comment: Voting to close as genealogies of living persons are off-topic here. Maybe ok on Politics SE but I can't speak for them.

Comment: It is not a genealogic question per se.  The genealogical issue is merely incidental. The main point is of profound historical significance, especially with respect to African history and colonialism. For these reasons, I dissent with the decision to close the question.

Comment: The "of living persons" was probably the important part there. The #1 rule of thumb on this site is: "Did the question use any past-tense verbs?"